# BibTex and Webpages

Tags: bibtex, citing

I have this entry in my `manuscript.bib`:

```
@webpage{dartmouth,
    Date-Added = {2017-01-20 18:11:49 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-01-20 18:12:24 +0000},
    Lastchecked = {Friday, January 20, 2017},
    Url = {http://www.dartmouthatlas.org/data/region/},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://www.dartmouthatlas.org/data/region/}}
```

I'm using `pdflatexmk` to compile the document using TexShop.  The citation remains a question mark in the compiled document body, and `pdflatexmk` tells me: `Latex failed to resolve 1 citation(s)`.  Nothing new shows up in the bibliography.

I have other entries in `manuscript.bib` as well, they show up fine.  Is this related to the fact that this is a webpage?

Comment: I'm using BibDesk.  That was probably important information to include.  I just chose webpage in the drop-down.

Comment: or more exactly which bibtex style are you using? without knowing that it is impossible to say what is or is not supported

Comment: So, I changed to `@misc` and the problem remains.  I guess I need to dig into the `.bst` file.

Comment: standard styles such as `\bibligraphystyle{plain}` do not have a website entry type (they are older than the web for one reason...)

Comment: Still no luck after trying `@url`, `@misc`.  I'm using `ormsv080.bst`.  You can see it [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiejtPUr9HRAhVFTCYKHeEVCv4QFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iro.umontreal.ca%2F~lecuyer%2Ftex%2Flatex%2Fmacros%2Formsv080.bst&usg=AFQjCNG8wlWkILW-aHtJK18lUQ8LFqAeiQ&sig2=-qb8xZWMRCHSlen6IHHIkw)

Comment: that has a misc entry type, see `FUNCTION {misc}....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default bibtex styles do not have a webpage entry type. the bibdesk FAQ

https://sourceforge.net/p/bibdesk/wiki/FAQ/

says

> The bibtex style (bst file, specified in the
>
> \bibliographystyle{}
>
> command) you are using must be aware of the BibTeX-type "webpage" and
>   know what to do with "Lastchecked" or "Url". This is done by
>   http://purl.org/nxg/dist/urlbst

so you need to use one of the bibtex styles suggested, or use a generic type such as @misc.